# Generate Device token in android for react native app

Tags: android, react-native, devicetoken

I've tried to generate device token using FCM in android device. But got the following issue [image: fcm_error]

I've updated `Google play services` and checked the path of `google-services.json` all seems to be fine , but still same error. Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Show us your gradle file, then only we can identify exact issue.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

Comment: This is my app-level-gradle file